# Using spring-boot-maven-plugin to generate multiple runnable JAR

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have 2 classes with main method in my project.
When I use spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.0, I can generate 2 runnable JARs by configuration:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.myproj.Importer</mainClass>
            <classifier>importer</classifier>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>exe2</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.myproj.Reporter</mainClass>
            <classifier>reporter</classifier>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

maven package log is

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1:jar (default-jar) @ utility ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Workspaces\utility\target\utility-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ utility ---
[INFO] Attaching archive: D:\Workspaces\utility\target\utility-1.0-importer.jar, with classifier: importer
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:repackage (exe2) @ utility ---
[INFO] Attaching archive: D:\Workspaces\utility\target\utility-1.0-reporter.jar, with classifier: reporter
```

the JAR can be run like: `java -jar utility-1.0-importer.jar` & `java -jar utility-1.0-reporter.jar`

But when I use newest spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.1.RELEASE, same configuration produce 
`Unable to find a single main class` problem and I can't find alternative way to do the same thing.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you add `<version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>` below `<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>` in pom.xml and retry, this should work

Comment: No luck!I added and Eclipse has a warning `Duplicating managed version 2.2.1.RELEASE for spring-boot-maven-plugin` and still fail.

Comment: also change `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.0` to `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.1`

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, and failed!. If I added version 2.2.1 to maven-plugin only but kept starter-parent at 2.0.0, it will show `Overriding managed version 2.0.0.RELEASE for spring-boot-maven-plugin` and built 2 JARs successfully. But I want to upgrade my whole project to 2.2.1!!

Comment: Use spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.0 & spring-boot-maven-plugin 2.2.1, worked!.   Use starter-parent 2.2.1 & maven-plugin 2.0.0, failed!   Is it starter-parent's problem but not maven-plugin's problem?  But it is maven-plugin that do actual repackage work, wired!!!

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.x (latest is 2.0.9) are all OK but failed starting from 2.1.0. But I can't find anything about this in spring boot 2.1 release notes. =(